# Max and min in Scheme

Tags: scheme, max, racket, min

I need to get the max and min of a list in scheme. (We're not allowed to use the built-in functions.) There's something wrong with the code below. I am not sure what, maybe with the parentheses. Can anyone help?

```
#lang racket

(define (maxmin L)
  (cond 
    ((null? L) '()) 
    ((null? (cdr L)) (list (car L) (car L))) 
    (else (let((mmtemp(maxmin (cdr L)))
               (first (car L)))
            (cond(( > first (car mmtemp))
                  (cons first(cdr mmtemp)))
                 (( < first (car mmtemp))
                  (list (car mmtemp) first))
                 else (temp))))))     

( maxmin 1 2 3)
```

Comment: I take it using [`max`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=max#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._max%29%29) is out of the question? ;p

Comment: right we cannot use the max and min functions that scheme has

Comment: "there is something wrong" do you mean that you get a compilation error?  Or the code produces unexpected results?  Or has an error?  `else (temp)` looks wrong, offhand.  Shouldn't it be `(cond ... (else (temp)))`?  Or `(cond ... (else temp))`?  (I'm not sure whether temp is supposed to be a function that you want to call, or a variable whose value you want to return.)

Comment: But you're also defining a function with `(define (maxmin L) ...)` that will take *one* argument, and you're calling it with three in `(maxmin 1 2 3)`.  If you want to call it with multiple arguments, you'd need to do `(define (maxmin . L) ...)`.

Comment: thank you Joshua, you helped me figure out my careless mistake. firstly the temp was suppose to be mmtemp - I accidentally used the wrong variable, and had to put () around the else.

Comment: right i also realized that and i changed it. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is the last line:

```
else (temp))))))
```

The parentheses are incorrect here—the `else` keyword needs to be within the parens. Changing that to this:

```
(else temp))))))
```

...fixes the algorithm.

You also aren't calling `maxmin` properly—it needs a list, not a series of parameters. Your final line of the program should be as follows:

```
(maxmin '(1 2 3))
```

Those changes will make your program work properly.

---

However, your code is not very idiomatic Racket. It's very Scheme-like, and while Racket is a Scheme derivative, it is a separate language with its own set of idioms.

If you want to write idiomatic Racket code, you can use square brackets in place of parentheses in various places to aid in readability. Furthermore, you can use `first` instead of `car` and `rest` instead of `cdr` for operations on lists to make things more clear.

Incorporating those changes leads to code that is (in my opinion) more readable.

```
#lang racket

(define (max-min lst)
  (cond 
    [(null? lst) '()]
    [(null? (rest lst))
     (list (first lst) (first lst))]
    [else
     (let ([rst (max-min (rest lst))]
           [fst (first lst)])
       (cond
         [(> fst (first rst))
          (cons fst (rest rst))]
         [(< fst (first rst))
          (list (first rst) fst)]
         [else rst]))]))

(max-min '(1 2 3))
```